# Which is suitable for performance use Entity Framework Core or ADO.NET?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ado.net

I work on a Blazor application server side, I design Web API to interact with Razor pages.

My issue is which is suitable for my scenario - using ADO.NET or Entity Framework Core?

What I try as below :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAllServersDetails")]
public IActionResult GetAllServersDetails()
{
    string query = "";

    query = "select s.ServerID, s.Server_Name as ServerName,isnull(s.ServerIp,'') as ServerIp,s.ServerTypeId,isnull(st.ServerType,'') as ServerType,s.OsTypeId,isnull(os.DetailsName,'')  as OsType,s.HostedZoneId,isnull(hostedzone.DetailsName,'') as HostedZone,s.ServerityId,isnull(serverity.DetailsName,'') as Serverity,s.HostedTypeId,isnull(hostedType.DetailsName,'') as HostedType,isnull(s.ServerRoleId,0) as ServerRoleId,isnull(serverrole.DetailsName,'') as ServerRole,isnull(s.DRRequired,0) as DRRequiredID,isnull(drrequired.DetailsName,'') as DRRequired,isnull(s.Remarks,'') as Remarks,isnull(s.OwnerFileNo,'') as ownerfilenumber, s.IsActive from [dbo].[ServerNames] s with(nolock)
inner join [dbo].[ServerTypes] st with(nolock) on st.ServerTypeId=s.ServerTypeId
left join  Details os with(nolock) on os.ID=s.OsTypeId and os.HeaderId=12
left join  Details hostedzone with(nolock) on hostedzone.ID=s.HostedZoneId and hostedzone.HeaderId=13
left join  Details serverity with(nolock) on serverity.ID=s.ServerityId and serverity.HeaderId=14
left join  Details hostedType with(nolock) on hostedType.ID=s.HostedTypeId and hostedType.HeaderId=15
left join  Details serverrole with(nolock) on serverrole.ID=s.ServerRoleId and serverrole.HeaderId=16
left join  Details drrequired with(nolock) on drrequired.ID=s.DRRequired and drrequired.HeaderId=17";

    try
    {
        ICollection<object> ApplicationsDataValues = new List<object>();

        using (var command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            _context.Database.OpenConnection();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ApplicationsDataValues.Add(new
                            {
                                ServerID = reader.GetFieldValue<Int32>(0),
                                ServerName = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(1).ToString(),
                                ServerIp = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(2).ToString(),
                                ServerTypeId = reader.GetFieldValue<Int32>(3),
                                
                                ServerType = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(4).ToString(),
                                OsTypeId = reader.GetFieldValue<Int32>(5),
                                
                                OsType = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(6).ToString(),
                                HostedZoneId = reader.GetFieldValue<Int32>(7),
                                
                                HostedZone = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(8).ToString(),

                                ServerityId = reader.GetFieldValue<Int32>(9),
                                Serverity = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(10).ToString(),

                                HostedTypeId = reader.GetFieldValue<Int32>(11),
                                HostedType = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(12).ToString(),

                                ServerRoleId = reader.GetFieldValue<Int32>(13),
                                ServerRole = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(14).ToString(),

                                DRRequiredID = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(15).ToString(),
                                DRRequired = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(16).ToString(),
                                
                                Remarks = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(17).ToString(),
                                ownerfilenumber = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(18).ToString(),
                                
                                IsActive = reader.GetFieldValue<bool>(19)//.ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(200, ApplicationsDataValues); // Get all users   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, e);
    }
}
```

So is using data reader in ADO.NET the best option, or using Entity Framework Core?

Some developers tell me why not to use ADO.NET - it is old technology and this is not good because it.

Open and close connection with every load page and Entity Framework Core does not do that.

Also is ADO.NET easy for hacking from Entity Framework Core? Is this correct?

Would it be better to use Entity Framework Core? I depend on code-first technology

Result of statement above is 10000 rows as maximum.

Comment: ADO.NET is **mature** technology - but not "old" as in outdated - not at all. ADO.NET is typically **faster** at runtime, but requires more coding from you - you need to be able to write efficient and secure SQL statements to run. EF Core is a lot more convenient for the developer - needs to think of less details, handles a lot of the "glue code" you need to write for ADO.NET - so it's more efficient from a programmer's productivity - but it's a layer on top of ADO.NET and thus typically slower

Answer (score 0):

EF uses ADO.Net under the hood, anyway.

However, if you specify an SQL statement and execute using ADO.Net directly, you'll not be involving the overhead of an ORM such as EF.

When you use EF, it needs to interpret your LINQ queries and translate to SQL.  Further, EF will track entities by default which involves setting up proxies for returned data.  This can be easily overridden by using AsNoTracking() when using EF to retrieve data that is not going to be edited.

However, the trade off in respect of time taken to translate LINQ to SQL, is that EF does make coding much much easier.  Best way is to benchmark your results using ADO.Net directly and using EF and then decide whether the trade-off in performance in worth the simplicity of code.

So, the answer to your question is "it depends on what you want to prioritize, performance or coding simplicity".

You could also take a look at Dapper as a lightweight ORM that somewhat simplifies the handling of data returned by an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to use an ORM typically involves more than one use case. For instance if you just want to read a block of data from a database then an ORM like EF is almost certainly overkill. What EF provides is a data layer for reading data, tracking changes, and transforming data into object models that are best suited for what the code needs. The advantages can include things like minimizing the amount of code/SQL you need to use, and offering some protections like parameterization to guard against things like SQL injection which you need to make sure you do consistently yourself with ADO.

The downside of using an ORM like EF is that while it is quite powerful and can produce pretty close to as efficient querying as you could write yourself, this requires time to learn about it's capabilities. Used incorrectly, it can lead to some absolutely stinker of performance issues if you start getting tripped up with lazy loading, or even abusing eager loading instead of projection for read operations. It can also look as messy, and involve as much manual cruft coding as ADO/SQL if you neglect things like navigation properties.

So in the case of what your above code would look like with EF done properly:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAllServersDetails")]
public IActionResult GetAllServersDetails()
{
    ICollection<object> ApplicationsDataValues = new List<object>();
    using var context = new AppDbContext(); // or better, dependency inject the DbContext in.

    try
    {
        var applicationDataValues = context.ServerNames
            .Select(x => new 
            {
                x.ServerId, 
                x.ServerName, // Entity can define ServerName with a DB Column name of Server_Name
                ServerIp = x.ServerIp ?? "",
                SeverType = x.ServerType.ServerType ?? "",
                OsType = x.OsType.DetailsName ?? "", 
                HostedZone =  x.HostedZone.DetailsName ?? "", 
                Severity = x.Serverity.DetailsName ?? "",  
                HostedType = x.HostedType.DetailsName ?? "",
                ServerRole = x.ServerRole.DetailsName ?? "",
                DRRequired = x.DRRequired.DetailsName ?? "",
                Remarks = x.Remarks ?? "",
                OwnerFileNumber = x.OwnerFileNo ?? "", 
                x.IsActive 
            }).ToList();

        return StatusCode(200, applicationsDataValues); // Get all users   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, e);
    }
         
}
```

This assumes the database is properly normalized, and the entities are set up with navigation properties for the relationships. From your original SQL it wasn't clear what the significance of the HeaderId=# were in each of the joins. Normally in a many-to-one the FK is sufficient to relate rows to one another.

The above query uses projection to tell EF that you want to use the entity definitions to build an SQL statement to retrieve just the data requested. This differs from the default go-to behaviour when people first learn about EF which is loading and tracking instances of the entities themselves. With projection you don't need to worry about things like lazy loading and eager loading costs, it is a performant option for read-only operations across related entities.